# Cannot access window.location.search in EmberJS Fastboot beforeModel

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am using EmberJS Fastboot and I cannot access `window.location.search` in the `beforeModel`. I can however access `window.location` and `search` is populated when I open the object.

```
beforeModel(transition) {
  console.log(window.location) // returns object with populated search
  console.log(window.location.search) // undefined
}
```

I expected `window.location.search` not to be undefined because it is populated when I call `window.location`

Comment: This behaves the same way in the `model` hook too.

Comment: Is this a fastboot app?

Comment: Yes!! it is fastboot. I'll update the question.

Comment: Cool.  So while in fastboot, `window` is not accessible.  In node, we only have access to the request response cycle.  We also build out a [DOM](https://github.com/ember-fastboot/simple-dom) that we can walk and query, but still no `window` or `document`.  Effectively there are two phases - 1. node, 2. browser.  Since `search` only is "useful" after the browser (aka user) has taken over, I'm guessing you don't need to access this in fastboot.  Is there something else I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any '?' for the search string, if not, the `window.location.search` won't work. Try adding the search string correctly and then check if it works

Comment: I am using '?' The search value is evident in `window.location` but I am unable to access any property such as search or port.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Fastboot, you can access query parameters like these: `this.fastboot.request.queryParams` (`FastBoot` is a service)

See [Documantation](https://ember-fastboot.com/docs/user-guide#query-parameters)

Comment: Thanks I was using this but discovered it would not parse duplicate object keys. Just my luck our urls use duplicate object keys.

Comment: what about `this.fastboot.request.query` ? If it is not work, can you dump `this.fastboot.request`?

Comment: Thanks I'll try that, currently I'm getting the URL form `transition.intent.url` and then splitting at the `?`

Comment: I didn't know that. Is it documented? Also `transition.queryParams` may also work then.

Comment: I don't think it's documented but I found it out through trial and error, also saw it in another SO comment. `transition.queryParams` would be awesome but if it encounters duplicate items it only records the last entry. I unfortunately have many dupes in my urls.